# Drool condition in different lines vs condition in same line

Tags: drools

I have a rule as follows --

```
when 
      $myobj : 
                       myObject( eval( condition1))//new line
                       myObject( eval(condition 2) && condition3)
```

In above case if my condition2 is evaluating to false even then condition 3 is executed.

However in my below code where all conditions are in same line, the short circuit && works as expected - when condition 2 is false , condition 3 is not evaluated.

```
when 
      $myobj : 
                       myObject( eval( condition1) && eval(condition 2) && condition3))
```

Why are the above blocks of code behaving differently

Answer (score 0):

Drools syntax is free-format and line ends do not matter.

The two left hand sides are fundamentally different.

```
myObject( eval( condition1) )
myObject( eval( condition2 ) && condition3 )
```

The preceding LHS matches if you have one myObject fulfilling all constraints **or** if you have one myObject matching condition1 and another myObject matching condition2 and condition3.

```
myObject( eval( condition1 ) && eval( condition2 ) && condition3 )
```

The preceding pattern requires all three constraints to be true for one myObject.

Comment: Even if that is the case condition 3 should not be evaluated if condition 2 is false because of '&&' operator

Comment: Provide a documentation reference and a contradicting example, full code, if you claim you have found a bug. - Constraint evaluation isn't necessarily following the rules of Java or some other programming language.